# How to find and edit "Apache timeout"?

Tags: centos, configuration, search, apache-httpd, timeout

I'm trying to view the default value of Apache timeout of my server, but I found nothing about that in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` . So where is " timeout " supposed to be and how do I change its value ?

The OS is Centos 7 | Apache version : 2.4.6

Comment: Please check the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629566/how-to-increase-apache-timeout-directive-in-htaccess

Comment: I've looked at it before I post this question... but it doesn't work with me neither by adding new timeout value in `httpd.conf` nor by creating a new `conf` file in `conf.d` and then adding the new timeout value inside. It seems ( but I'm not sure ) the server still use the default value which is mostly `300 second` .

Comment: Please update your question with the version of apache you use. As well as additional modules (if implemented)

Comment: I updated the question with Apache version ... There are a lot of modules installed now, I cannot really distinguish the additional ones.

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation to give this as answer, but try: httpd -DDUMP_CONFIG -k start | grep TimeOut

Answer (score 6):

From
[Apache docs: timeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout)
This should be written to server httpd.conf:

```
TimeOut Num
```

More info from the above link:

```
Syntax: TimeOut seconds
Default:    TimeOut 300
Context:    server config, virtual host
```

Also, if you need to increase your script execution time, that's

```
max_execution_time 60
```

in php.ini (number is seconds)

Comment: In my server it's not written neither in `httpd.conf` nor in any other file in `/etc/httpd/` ... and after I created a new conf file and then added `Timeout` value inside, I cannot test by a proven way what is the exact value of `Timeout` that my server is using at this moment.

Answer (score 4):

I bet you are using php-fpm. This is a known bug in Apache 2.4.6.
Timeout and ProxyTimeout are ignored and the value 30s is hardcoded.

It is fixed in Apache 2.4.8.

Here are two links you should read

[bugzilla error post](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54973#c6)

[Solution if you intend to recompile Apache on your own](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=30833&action=diff)